# Can't import database Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, database, import, magento2.3.3

I have created a backup database by command line:

> php bin/magento setup:backup --db

Then I import it to my new PHPMyAdmin, But it shows a bug:

Static analysis:

```
4 errors were found during analysis.

    Unexpected character. (near "\" at position 0)
    Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "\" at position 0)
    Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "nCREATE" at position 1)
    Unrecognized statement type. (near "ALGORITHM" at position 9)

SQL query: Documentation

\nCREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED SQL SECURITY INVOKER VIEW `inventory_stock_1` AS select distinct `legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`website_id` AS `website_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_id` AS `stock_id`,`legacy_stock_status`.`qty` AS `quantity`,`legacy_stock_status`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`,`product`.`sku` AS `sku` from (`cataloginventory_stock_status` `legacy_stock_status` join `catalog_product_entity` `product` on((`legacy_stock_status`.`product_id` = `product`.`entity_id`)))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to import the database in your new `PHPMyAdmin` by following the below few steps.

**Step 1:** Export the database using the below command with `SSH`

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME > DATABASE_FILENAME.sql
```

**Step 2:** Upload the exported database file on the new server where you want to import it.

**Step 3:** You can import the database on the new server using the below command with `SSH`

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p DATABASE_NAME < DATABASE_FILENAME.sql
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! I try but it shows a bug https://prnt.sc/q0h2pz. I think the issue is file SQL have bug.

Comment: Yes, may be. Are you exporting the database from the Window operating system?

Comment: Yes, I work with XAMPP on Windows.

Comment: I have checked it works on my server!

Answer (score 1):

You can go to Magento root by SSH and apply below command to your database:
First upload your exported database file "yourimportedSqlFile.sql" at Magento root folder structure:
Now run command as below:

```
mysql -u username -p your databasename < yourimportedSqlFile.sql
```

Comment: Thank you! It still shows a bug. Please check my screen: http://prntscr.com/q0h2pz.

Answer (score 1):

could you please disable magento backups and install this tool:
https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun2

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar
```

and try this command:

```
n98-magerun2.phar db:dump
```

see if then import works without errors.

Comment: Thank you! I have export and import use PHPMyAdmin and it works fine, now. And I think there must be an easy solution more than install extension.

Comment: this is not an extension. this is extended magento 2 cli

Comment: Ok, Thank you! I think this can work but it's complicated.

Answer (score 0):

I use Xampp and Windows. I found so a simple solution is just search "\nCREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED" in file SQL, then remove \n with enter.

Hope it helps someone!